# Incomplete type when generating compile time integer range

Tags: c++, templates

I have trouble generating a compile time integer range. this is my code:

```
#include<type_traits>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

// this is needed because I'm using vs2013
template<typename T, T...Seq>
struct integer_sequence{
    using type = integer_sequence<T, Seq...>;
};

template<typename T>
struct ToMemberType {
    using type = T;
};


template<typename TTest, typename TCount, typename TResult>
struct ImplMakeIntegerRange;

template<typename T, T Begin, T End, T...Seq>
struct ImplMakeIntegerRange<
        integer_sequence<T, Begin>,
        integer_sequence<T, End>,
        integer_sequence<T, Seq...>
    >
    :
    conditional<
        is_same<
            integer_sequence<T, Begin>,
            integer_sequence<T, End>
        >::value,
        integer_sequence<T, Seq...>,
        ToMemberType <
            ImplMakeIntegerRange<
                integer_sequence<T, Begin>,
                integer_sequence<T, End - 1>,
                integer_sequence<T, End - 1, Seq...>
            >
        >
    >::type {
    static_assert(Begin <= End, "Begin <= End failed");
};

template<typename T, T Begin, T End>
using make_integer_range =
    typename ImplMakeIntegerRange <
        integer_sequence<T, Begin>,
        integer_sequence<T, End>,
        integer_sequence < T >
    >::type;

// the code below is to test if make_integer_range really works.
template<typename T>
struct PrintIntegerRange;

template<typename T, T...Seq>
struct PrintIntegerRange<integer_sequence<T, Seq...>>{
public:
    static void Print() {
        for (auto a : { Seq... }) {
            cout << a << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    //I expect this two print the same result.
    PrintIntegerRange<integer_sequence<int, 3, 4, 5>>::Print();
    PrintIntegerRange<make_integer_range<int, 3, 6>>::Print(); //got three error here.

}
```

The code above never compiled. The last line produce three error messages:

1. error C2027: use of undefined type 'PrintIntegerRange'
2. error C3861: 'Print': identifier not found
3. IntelliSense: incomplete type is not allowed

Again, I'm using vs2013. Where am I wrong?

Edit:
ps. The code compile and have the expected result if the last line is removed.

Comment: missing a `::type` in `PrintIntegerRange<integer_sequence<int, 3, 4, 5>>` after integer_sequence<>? Also please don't use `using namespace std;`

Comment: @erenon `integer_sequence<>` and `integer_sequence<>::type` are actually the same type. And only the last line prevent the code from compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in usage of ToMemberType struct. You have to remove it from ImplMakeIntegerRange definition or to extract its template parameter type like this

```
template<typename T, T Begin, T End, T...Seq>
struct ImplMakeIntegerRange<
        integer_sequence<T, Begin>,
        integer_sequence<T, End>,
        integer_sequence<T, Seq...>
    >
    :
    conditional<
        is_same<
            integer_sequence<T, Begin>,
            integer_sequence<T, End>
        >::value,
        integer_sequence<T, Seq...>,
        typename ToMemberType <
            ImplMakeIntegerRange<
                integer_sequence<T, Begin>,
                integer_sequence<T, End - 1>,
                integer_sequence<T, End - 1, Seq...>
            >
        >::type
    >::type {
    static_assert(Begin <= End, "Begin <= End failed");
};
```